# Jekyll Build error

Tags: ruby, jekyll

I am trying to build a jekyll site with the command `jekyll build`. When I run the command I get the following error:

```
    /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.1/lib/bundler/rubygems_ext.rb:45:in `full_gem_path': uninitialized constant Bundler::Plugin::API::Source (NameError)
    from /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1393:in `contains_requirable_file?'
    from /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `block in require'
    from /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:823:in `block in each'
    from /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:822:in `each'
    from /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:822:in `each'
    from /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:67:in `find'
    from /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:67:in `require'
    from /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.1/lib/bundler/plugin/api/source.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.1/lib/bundler/rubygems_ext.rb:45:in `full_gem_path'
    from /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1393:in `contains_requirable_file?'
    from /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `block in require'
    from /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:823:in `block in each'
    from /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:822:in `each'
    from /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:822:in `each'
    from /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:67:in `find'
    from /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:67:in `require'
    from /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.1/lib/bundler.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `require'
    from /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `rescue in require'
    from /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:144:in `require'
    from /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/jekyll-3.2.1/lib/jekyll/plugin_manager.rb:34:in `require_from_bundler'
    from /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/jekyll-3.2.1/exe/jekyll:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bin/jekyll:23:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/jekyll:23:in `<main>'
```

I am running Ruby version 2.2. My server is Amazon Linux AMI. Let me know if there is any other information needed to answer the question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up figuring this out. Apparently I was missing a javascript environment. Steps:

1. `sudo rm -r Gemfile.lock`
2. `nano Gemfile`. Add `gem 'therubyracer'`. Save and exit
3. `bundle install`
4. `bundle exec jekyll build`

This fixed the problem for me!

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue. This happens when you haven't initialized bundler and jekyll dependencies.

To fix this,

1. Go to root directory containing your jekyll files
2. Run `jekyll new . --force`. This will initialize the current folder with bundler and jekyll dependencies
3. Now run the server using `bundler exec jekyll serve`

`jekyll new . --force` works like `git init` for a new git repository. See the [documentation](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/quickstart/) for more information